# Area of Parallelogram

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Calculate the area of the parallelogram from vectors $M$ and $N$.
$$M=(1, 2, 4)$$
$$N=(3,0,2)$$

I did this by the formula Area$=|M \times N|$.

I got $\sqrt{ 136}$ units.

is this the right way and answer? 
thank you

Comment: Kindly include your working in your future posts especially if you want others to check your working.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is correct, but the answer might not be correct.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 4\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 10 \\ -6\end{bmatrix} $$

$$\sqrt{4^2+10^2+6^2}=\sqrt{16+100+36}$$

Answer (score 2):

You have the right approach, however you may have made an arithmetic error. We have:
$$\begin{align}M\times N&=\det\begin{bmatrix}\hat i&\hat j&\hat k\\1&2&4\\3&0&2\end{bmatrix}\\&=\hat i\left((2)(2)-(0)(4)\right)-\hat j\left((1)(2)-(3)(4)\right)+\hat k\left((1)(0)-(3)(2)\right)\\&=4\hat i+10\hat j-6\hat k\\&=(4,10,-6)\end{align}$$
then
$$|M\times N|=\sqrt{(4)^2+(10)^2+(-6)^2}=\sqrt{16+100+36}=\sqrt{152}$$

Answer (score 1):

You way is right because you calculate a volume of parallelepiped with area of base, which you need, and the altitude $1$, but there is a mistake in your computations.

I like the following way.
$$\cos\measuredangle(M,N)=\frac{M\cdot N}{|M|\cdot|N|}=\frac{1\cdot3+2\cdot0+4\cdot2}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2+4^2}\cdot\sqrt{3^2+0^2+2^2}}=\frac{11}{\sqrt{273}}.$$ 
Thus, the area is
$$|M|\cdot|N|\sin\measuredangle(M,N)=\sqrt{273}\cdot\sqrt{1-\frac{121}{273}}=2\sqrt{38}.$$